# send_file return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Does the `send_file` method in Rails give a return value? I'd like to do one thing if the sending is successful, and another thing if the sending is *not* successful. I looked at the documentation at [this link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file), but did not find anything relevant.

Comment: What does "sending is not successful" mean, precisely? Presumably you don't mean there was an error in `send_file`, since you could respond to that using standard exception handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to confirm download completion or success with `send_file`. From this question: [Can we find out when a Paperclip download is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787625/can-we-find-out-when-a-paperclip-download-is-complete) :

> `send_file` creates the file and then passes a special header to tell
>   the webserver telling it what to send. Rails doesn't actually send the
>   file at all, it sets this header which tells the webserver to send the
>   file but then returns immediately, and moves on to serve another
>   request. To be able to track if the download completes you'd have to
>   occupy your Rails application process sending the file and block until
>   the user downloads it, instead of leaving that to the webserver (which
>   is what its designed to do). This is super inefficient.

You may be able to do something using cookies and JavaScript on the client.
See this question: [Rails File Download And View Update - Howto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945422/rails-file-download-and-view-update-howto)